# What is the recommended way to create multiple paths starting from the same parent directory?

Tags: path, rust

I have a function that receives a `PathBuf` and it creates a bunch of files and directories within the path of that `PathBuf`. For example, the function gets `foo/bar` and it will create directories/files like `foo/bar/bazinga` and `foo/bar/foo`.

I can use e.g. `fs::create_dir[_all](path: PathBuf)` and create a `PathBuf` instance for every single folder/file I want to create. However, creating such an instance means I'll have to clone the incoming `PathBuf`:

```
pub fn generate(&self, mut path: PathBuf) -> Result<()> {
    let dir_to_be_created_path = path.clone();
    dir_to_be_created_path.push("bazinga");
    Ok(())
}
```

Another option would be to take `&mut PathBuf` instead and `push()` and `pop()` as needed, working with essentially only one instance reference instead.

Is it fair to say that one of these options is a "better" way to do this? Or are there other options on how this could be done for the better?

Comment: Have you profiled your code and found that the act of *creating paths* is a significant bottleneck? I'd expect that creating the entries on disk would greatly outweigh any time spend in making up their names.

Comment: See also [What is a macro for concatenating an arbitrary number of components to build a path in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40567020/155423)

Comment: Thank you! No I haven't, was just asking up front because I keep reading in different places that copying data can be a problem. Obviously that also depends on the size. It indeed probably doesn't matter here.

Appreciate your thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`Path::join()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.join). It combines the `.clone()` and `.push()` into a single step.

Comment: Ah, wonderful!! That looks like exactly what I need! Any comments on working with clones vs working with a borrowed PathBuf?